# Passing ListView by using Intent

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, android-activity

I have created a List View containing-

- "Baby Items"
- "Bakery"
- "Baking"
- "Beverages"
- "Canned Goods"
- "Cereal Breakfast"
- "Condiments"
- "Dairy"
- "Frozen Foods"
- "Miscellaneous"
- "Non-Food Items"
- "Pasta / Rice"
- "Snacks"

Then, I want to create an onClick layout to each list view also.

> How can I use intent for the Baby_Items layout if I click on the Baby Items in Shopping Items (ListView)

## Shopping Items (JAVA)

```
public class ShoppingItems extends ActionBarActivity {
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] item_category = {"Baby Items", "Bakery", "Baking",
        "Beverages", "Canned Goods", "Cereal Breakfast", "Condiments",
        "Dairy", "Frozen Foods", "Miscellaneous", "Non-Food Items",
        "Pasta / Rice", "Snacks"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping_items);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,item_category);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+ " is selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

## BABY_ITEMS (JAVA)

```
public class Baby_Items extends ActionBarActivity {

ArrayList<Products> products = new ArrayList<Products>();
ListAdapter boxAdapter;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_baby__items);

    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvbabyitems);
    lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);
}

void fillData() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        products.add(new Products("Products " + i, i * 100, false));

    }
}

public void showResult(View v) {
    String result = "Selected Product are :";
    int totalAmount=0;
    for (Products p : boxAdapter.getBox()) {
        if (p.box){
            result += "\n" + p.name;
            totalAmount+=p.price;
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, result+"\n"+"Total Amount:="+totalAmount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) for understanding basics about `ListView` implementation.You can use Intent for starting new `Activity` on `ListView` item click.

Answer (score 0):

try this in onClick Method

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+ " is selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             Intent intent = new Intent(ShoppingItems.this, Baby_Items.class);
            intent.putExtra("baby_item", "" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

and in Baby_Items activty get extra data like

```
if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("baby_item")) {

            String item = getIntent().getStringExtra("baby_item");

        }
```

Comment: Hi sir! Can you please guide me.. Coz, I dont know which part do I put your codes.

Comment: But the "parent" and "position" are red. I tried to remove that line and play?

Comment: intent.putExtra("baby_item", "" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position)); 
The parent and position of that line

Comment: just copy n paste above portion of list View click listener.. it will work fine.. it has no error..